# I have an Array of objects, in all objects I have delete some data

Tags: javascript

I have an Array of objects, In all objects I have event_date_utc: 2008-09-28T23:15:00Z here event_date_utc is a key and value is 2008-09-28T23:15:00Z.  Now I want to show in value only date like this 2008-09-28  so how can I achieve this in javascript

This is my code

```
const data = [
    {
        "title": "Falcon 1 Makes History",
        "event_date_utc": "2008-09-28T23:15:00Z",
        "flight_number": 4,
        "details": "Falcon 1 becomes the first privately developed liquid fuel rocket to reach Earth orbit.",
    },
    {
        "title": "SpaceX Wins $1.6B CRS Contract",
        "event_date_utc": "2008-12-23T01:00:00Z",
        "flight_number": null,
        "details": "NASA awards SpaceX $1.6B Commercial Resupply Services (CRS) contract.",
    },
    {
        "title": "Falcon 1 Flight 5 Makes History",
        "event_date_utc": "2009-07-13T03:35:00Z",
        "flight_number": 5,
        "details": "Falcon 1 Flight 5 makes history, becoming the first privately developed liquid fuel rocket to deliver a commercial satellite to Earth orbit."
    },
    {
        "title": "Falcon 9 First Flight",
        "event_date_utc": "2010-06-04T18:45:00Z",
        "flight_number": 6,
        "details": "Met 100% of mission objectives on the first flight!"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dragon Returns From Earth Orbit",
        "event_date_utc": "2010-12-08T15:43:00Z",
        "flight_number": 7,
        "details": "On December 8, 2010, Dragon became the first privately developed spacecraft in history to re-enter from low-Earth orbit."
    },
    {
        "title": "First Dragon Visit to Space Station",
        "event_date_utc": "2012-10-08T00:35:00Z",
        "flight_number": 9,
        "details": "Dragon becomes the first private spacecraft in history to visit the space station."
    },
    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just want to modify the dates and then have the new array containing sanitized dates. for that you can do it in place like this.

```js
var data = [{
    "title": "Falcon 1 Makes History",
    "event_date_utc": "2008-09-28T23:15:00Z",
    "flight_number": 4,
    "details": "Falcon 1 becomes the first privately developed liquid fuel rocket to reach Earth orbit.",
  },
  {
    "title": "SpaceX Wins $1.6B CRS Contract",
    "event_date_utc": "2008-12-23T01:00:00Z",
    "flight_number": null,
    "details": "NASA awards SpaceX $1.6B Commercial Resupply Services (CRS) contract.",
  },
  {
    "title": "Falcon 1 Flight 5 Makes History",
    "event_date_utc": "2009-07-13T03:35:00Z",
    "flight_number": 5,
    "details": "Falcon 1 Flight 5 makes history, becoming the first privately developed liquid fuel rocket to deliver a commercial satellite to Earth orbit."
  },
  {
    "title": "Falcon 9 First Flight",
    "event_date_utc": "2010-06-04T18:45:00Z",
    "flight_number": 6,
    "details": "Met 100% of mission objectives on the first flight!"
  },
  {
    "title": "Dragon Returns From Earth Orbit",
    "event_date_utc": "2010-12-08T15:43:00Z",
    "flight_number": 7,
    "details": "On December 8, 2010, Dragon became the first privately developed spacecraft in history to re-enter from low-Earth orbit."
  },
  {
    "title": "First Dragon Visit to Space Station",
    "event_date_utc": "2012-10-08T00:35:00Z",
    "flight_number": 9,
    "details": "Dragon becomes the first private spacecraft in history to visit the space station."
  },

];

data.forEach((item) => item.event_date_utc = item.event_date_utc.substr(0, 10));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `filter`

```
const filteredData = data.filter(
  (d) => d.event_date_utc.split("T")[0] === "2008-09-28"
)

console.log(filteredData)
```

**Full example**

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: "Falcon 1 Makes History",
    event_date_utc: "2008-09-28T23:15:00Z",
    flight_number: 4,
    details:
      "Falcon 1 becomes the first privately developed liquid fuel rocket to reach Earth orbit.",
  },
  {
    title: "SpaceX Wins $1.6B CRS Contract",
    event_date_utc: "2008-12-23T01:00:00Z",
    flight_number: null,
    details:
      "NASA awards SpaceX $1.6B Commercial Resupply Services (CRS) contract.",
  },
  {
    title: "Falcon 1 Flight 5 Makes History",
    event_date_utc: "2009-07-13T03:35:00Z",
    flight_number: 5,
    details:
      "Falcon 1 Flight 5 makes history, becoming the first privately developed liquid fuel rocket to deliver a commercial satellite to Earth orbit.",
  },
  {
    title: "Falcon 9 First Flight",
    event_date_utc: "2010-06-04T18:45:00Z",
    flight_number: 6,
    details: "Met 100% of mission objectives on the first flight!",
  },
  {
    title: "Dragon Returns From Earth Orbit",
    event_date_utc: "2010-12-08T15:43:00Z",
    flight_number: 7,
    details:
      "On December 8, 2010, Dragon became the first privately developed spacecraft in history to re-enter from low-Earth orbit.",
  },
  {
    title: "First Dragon Visit to Space Station",
    event_date_utc: "2012-10-08T00:35:00Z",
    flight_number: 9,
    details:
      "Dragon becomes the first private spacecraft in history to visit the space station.",
  },
]

const filteredData = data.filter(
  (d) => d.event_date_utc.split("T")[0] === "2008-09-28"
)

console.log(filteredData)
```